# Spark: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver does not allow create table as select

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm getting the following error when attempting to save to a MySQL database through spark:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver does not allow create table as select.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateMetastoreDataSourceAsSelect.run(commands.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.execute(commands.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable(DataFrame.scala:1091)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My python code:

```
res.saveAsTable(tableName='test.provider_phones', source='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', mode='append', url='jdbc:mysql://host.amazonaws.com:port/test?user=user&password=pass')
```

This happens whether or not the table already exists.

I am using spark 1.3.1

Comment: It won't solve your problem but I am pretty sure that `source` should be `jdbc` not `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in pyspark 1.3.1. My solution is to switch over to scala, and use `DataFrame.insertIntoJDBC`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `createJDBCTable(url: String, table: String, allowExisting: Boolean)` or  `insertIntoJDBC(url: String, table: String, overwrite: Boolean)` function of `DataFrame`.

http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/04/17/save-apache-spark-dataframe-to-database/

Comment: Thanks, but this question is about spark 1.3.1 in python.

Comment: my bad...didn't saw that

Comment: There actually isn't a solution in python, unfortunately.